# Loop Cutting with Python

Tags: modeling, python

I am trying to Loop Cut a Plane, made in the Code beforehand.

I cant find a short and precise online how to JUST do that.
All answers include some kind of fixing other issues.
Can someone post the code of simply:

create plane

loopcut plane in X-Direction a number of times

loopcut plane in Y-Direction a number of times

When making everything manually, the console posts the following lines to create the loopcut:

```
    bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(
    MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE', 
    "object_index":0, "edge_index":3, "mesh_select_mode_init":(True, False, False)}, 
    TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":0, "single_side":False, "use_even":False,
    "flipped":False, "use_clamp":True, "mirror":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST',
    "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
    "correct_uv":True, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
```

When I use that in my console it throws following Error:

```
    RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide.poll() expected a view3d region & editmesh
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking your question as a duplicate of: [Loop Cut and Slide using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43076/60486)

However since you mention you had a problem with existing answers, here's a minified version of the linked answer:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C


def main():
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    x_edge, y_edge = find_xy_edges(C.object.data)
    area = next(a for a in C.window.screen.areas if a.type == 'VIEW_3D')
    region = next(r for r in area.regions if r.type == 'WINDOW')
    c_override = {'area': area, 'region': region}
    loopcut(c_override, edge_index=x_edge, number_cuts=3)
    loopcut(c_override, edge_index=y_edge, number_cuts=10)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        
    
def find_xy_edges(mesh):
    x_edge = None
    y_edge = None
    verts = mesh.vertices
    for edge in mesh.edges:
        v1_i, v2_i = edge.vertices
        vec = verts[v1_i].co - verts[v2_i].co
        if vec.x > vec.y:
            x_edge = edge.index
        else:
            y_edge = edge.index
        if not (x_edge is None or y_edge is None):
            return x_edge, y_edge


def loopcut(override, *, edge_index, number_cuts):
    cutting_data = {
        "number_cuts"  : number_cuts,
        "object_index" : 0,
        "edge_index"   : edge_index,
    }
    bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(override, MESH_OT_loopcut=cutting_data)
    

main()
```

I wasn't sure if the `x_edge` and `y_edge` names perhaps should be swapped...